# LINQ TO SQL; insert/update/delete from DB using GridView control

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, gridview, metrics

I'm struggling with updating multiple DB tables using GridView control and Linq2Sql as well as creating appropriate metrics.

I've got 4 following tables;

ProductCategories { id, Name }

Products { id, Name, CategoryID }

RatedProducts { id, ProductID, UserID, Rating }

Users { id, Name }

```
User Name     Categories          Sweets        
               Products         M&Ms Skittles Mars
```

Mr Smith                            Good     Poor   Excellent

Now I need to populate GridView with dynamic UserNames in rows and all the prodcuts and their categories also dynamic in column names, then in actual rows underneath product names I need to have "rating" and whenever clicked update - changed to dropdown.

Hope someone can help me out here with a clever way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://www.webswapp.com/codesamples/aspnet20/dropdownlist_gridview/default.aspx) shows how to bind the GridView control to hierarchical data with a dropdown.  You will find a class (named clsOrder) is bound to the GridView.  One property of that list returns a list of another class (named clsProdListItem) which is bound to a dropdownlist using the databinding expression DataSource='<%#Eval("Products") %>' (where Products is the function that returns a list of clsProdListItems).  You can adopt this code to build a child GridView instead of the dropdown if you like.

Comment: Thanks but that's not exactly what I'm after. I need all in one GridView. I am not able to upload an image, unfortunately.